# Pip3 can't install face_recognition on macOS

Tags: python, macos, pip, face-recognition

On macOS I ran this command in Terminal:

```
sudo pip3 install face_recognition
```

It started installing and then threw this error:

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c
>   'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
>   '"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-75ks5d9l/dlib/setup.py'"'"';
>   **file**='"'"'/private/tmp/pip-install-75ks5d9l/dlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
>   '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
>   install --record /private/tmp/pip-record-bze0mci9/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8/dlib
>   Check the logs for full command output.

I read a suggestion about installing `dlib` first which also threw an error. How can I fix this?

Comment: The [GitHub readme's installation instructions](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition#installing-on-mac-or-linux) are fairly clear that you need to first install `dlib`, so you should probably post how you are trying to do that and the exact error you got when doing that. Have you followed the [linked guide on how to install `dlib` on MacOS or Ubuntu](https://gist.github.com/ageitgey/629d75c1baac34dfa5ca2a1928a7aeaf#how-to-install-dlib-v199-or-newer-w-python-bindings-from-github-on-macos-and-ubuntu)?

Comment: @MihaiChelaru thanks, completely forgot about checking the link

Comment: @Daniil That library is not yet supported or python 3.8 as far as I can tell, so you may need to use an older version of python (and pip).

Answer (score 2):

First install `cmake` using following command:

```
pip3 install cmake
```